# R Shiny: app works locally, deploying causes error due to local data

Tags: r, shiny

**ERROR: object 'final' not found**

This has been driving me insane. I've made sure to put my local dataset into a sub-directory called 'Data', read it in my server.R file using a relative path, and also made sure I can run the app locally (no issues there). Any leads?

server.R:

```
library(shiny)

library(ggplot2)
final <- read.csv("./Data/final.csv")
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    if (input$bad !="All"){
      final <- final[final$bad == input$bad,]
    }
    final
  }, options=list(rowCallback= I('function(row, data) {
                                   if (data[1] > 15 & data[4] == 0)
                                   $("td", row).css("background", "lightgreen");}'), paging=FALSE))

})
```

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Open Loans"),
    fluidRow(
      column(1, 
             selectInput("bad", 
                         "Bad:", 
                         c("All", 
                           unique(as.character(final$badPredict))))
      )        
    ),
    fluidRow(
      dataTableOutput(outputId="table")
    )    
  )  
)
```

Comment: whats the file/directory structure?
try adding one more ".": `final <- read.csv("../Data/final.csv")`

Comment: structure is:
/table/ui.R; 
/table/server.R; 
/table/Data/final.csv -- I'm deploying from within the /table/ folder